# Announcing an EL&U Mod Privileges Summit

Tags: discussion

A chat room has been created as an open forum for users with any mod privileges such as "vote to close". This chat room is intended for discussion and consensus building about what editorial direction users with mod privileges should take in light of the [closing of the English Language Learners proposal](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7911/on-the-closure-of-english-language-learners/7912#7912):

- [EL&U Mod Privileges Summit](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6144/elu-mod-privileges-summit)

Should we:

- Stay the course (continue to allow many basic Q&A)?
- Stick more to the EL&U charter (discourage basic Q&A)?
- Support even more basic Q&A?
- Something else?

### Background

The ELL proposal would have created a place for basic English Q&A, freeing EL&U to be more of the expert-to-expert site that it was originally envisioned to be. The ELL proposal has now been closed as too much of an overlap with what EL&U currently offers, because EL&U allows many basic Q&A.

Comment: Anyone with mod privileges including Vote To Close (3K+) can ping anyone in the room to be added. Anyone added should be added as an owner so they can add others with 3K+ rep.

Comment: I expect that this summit room will be used to discuss and come to an agreement on how our community would like to shape our close/delete vote policies that will then be presented to the entire community on Meta.

Comment: And maybe not presented all at once. We might come up with things we can agree on and post them individually as they emerge.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this chat room is only meant for >10k and mods; why not allow users who are new to English, who are disproportionately users with low-rep, to weigh in with their side?

Comment: Well, that is ... unfortunate. I have expressed my dissent with this closure privately.

Comment: I'm pleased to have just learned this saga has a new chapter: [reinstatement link](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/7934/reinstating-the-english-learners-proposal).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a situation that has since been resolved in a manner that obviates this discussion.